# Centering featured image in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I would like to center Wordpress featured image on my site: https://link.do/ibXD8

I cannot find suitable option in theme properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this rule to your CSS:

```
.page-header-image.grid-parent {
  text-align: center;
}
```

This element contains the image and has full width: Since the image is an inline element, `text-align: center;` will center it inside its container.

Comment: Finally it worked!

Comment: I don't see the downvote but you answered an off topic question with a negative 5 votes and 2 close votes. Not cool.

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/center-featured-imagine/
Add below css code it may fix your problem .

```css
.attachment-post-thumbnail {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

or

```css
. image {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: let me know if it is not working.

Comment: This one didn't work.

Comment: try text-align: center; in css